# How to correctly Register abstract, generic classes in startup.cs for Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I am trying to build an MVC service which calls 2 different APIs, an Amazon one and an Apple one. The code looks like this:

```
public abstract class ApiHttpCaller<T>
{
    protected static HttpClient _client;

    protected ApiHttpCaller()
    {

        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }

    public abstract Task<T> RetrieveApiResultAsync(string searchValue);
}
```

This ApiHttpCaller is implemented by my 2 specifics AmazonApiCaller and AppleApiCaller, let's take only one of them into account:

```
public class AmazonApiCaller : ApiHttpCaller<AmazonResponseModel>
{
    protected static IOptions<ApiUrls> _apiUrls;

    public AmazonApiCaller(IOptions<ApiUrls> apiUrls)
    {
        _apiUrls = apiUrls;
    }

    public override async Task<AmazonResponseModel> RetrieveApiResultAsync(string searchValue)
    {            
        ..logic to call the api..
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AmazonResponseModel>(responseBody);
    }
}
```

as you can see, correct me if the architecture is wrong, there is an **AmazonResponseModel** used as generics here. As you can imagine AmazonApi and AppleApi return 2 different models. That's why my abstract parent class ApiHttpCaller uses a generics **T** that into the specifc AmazonApiCaller becomes an **AmazonResponseModel**. Such APIs are called from my controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemsController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ApiHttpCaller<T>> _apiCallers;

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        var amazonCaller = _apiCallers.First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(AmazonApiCaller));
        var itemResult = await amazonCaller.RetrieveApiResultAsync(value);
        ..more logic to map the itemResult to a viewModel..
    }
}
```

So, first question is: do you think it's correct to use the genercis **T** in the controller that then becomes a specifc type inside each api caller?

Second and more important: I don't know how to register in Startup.cs the ApiHttpCallers in such a way that they get injected properly in my controller. First guess is:

```
services.AddSingleton<ApiCaller<T>, AmazonApiCaller<AmazonResponseModel>>();
services.AddSingleton<ApiCaller<T>, AppleApiCaller<AppleResponseModel>>();
```

point is Startup.cs doesn't know anything of **T** .

Comment: Hey, I changed my answer to more fit your needs. Please check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

services to be registred:

```
services.AddSingleton<ApiCaller<AmazonResponseModel>, AmazonApiCaller>();
services.AddSingleton<ApiCaller<AppleResponseModel>, AppleApiCaller>(); 
services.AddTransient(typeof(ItemsController<>));
```

Change the controller as follows:

```
public class ItemsController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApiHttpCaller<T> _apiCaller;
    public ItemsController(ApiHttpCaller<T> apicaller){
        _apiCaller = apicaller;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        // do something with the requested API Caller
    }
}
```

This should now inject the correct ApiCaller into your service.
Of course you need to specify the type when injecting an `ItemsController`:

```
// Constructor
public AnyClass(ItemsController<AmazonResponseModel> controller){
    // _apiCaller of controller will be AmazonApiCaller
}
```

---

Or maybe use another `IoC Container` like [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).

You could benefit from Features like Contextual and named Bindings, which is documented on their page.

Answer (score 0):

You DI registration is incorrect here. It should be like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ApiCaller<AmazonResponseModel>, AmazonApiCaller>();
 services.AddSingleton<ApiCaller<AppleResponseModel>, AppleApiCaller>();
```

you need to specify which generic would correspond to which implementation.